# parameter to custom links in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, href

: [image]

when the user clicks on the link formula 1, i want to redirect to     `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7`
instead of `http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula 1`

where 7 is the id of the Formula 1

my JSON response is like as below

```
  {"rows":[{"id":7,"person":"Michael Schumacher","type":"Sport","name":"Formula 1"},
          {"id":8,"person":"Lukas Podolski","type":"Sport","name":"Football"},
          {"id":9,"person":"Blaise Pascal","type":"Sport","name":"mathematics"},
          {"id":6,"person":"Albert Einstein","type":"Sport","name":"Physics"}]}
```

Code of jqgrid is

```
     jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({
     url:"***.****",
        datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames:['Name','Category','Subcategory'],
            colModel:[
               {name:'person',index:'person', width:150},
               {name:'type',index:'type', width:150},
               {name:'name',index:'name', width:150,        
                   formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        var cellPrefix = '';
                        return cellPrefix + '<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + cellvalue + '">' +
                               cellvalue + '</a>';
                    }}

            ],

            width:"647px",
            caption:"How to create custom Unobtrusive links"

        });
```

Comment: what is comming in cellvalue??

Comment: @Jai cellvalue is giving formula 1

Answer (score 2):

You can just replace `cellvalue` inside of the code of the custom formatter to `options.rowId`:

```
formatter: function (cellvalue, options) {
    return '<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + options.rowId + '">' +
            cellvalue + '</a>';
}
```

You should additionally fix your JSON data and use `"name":"Formula 1"` instead of `"name"="Formula 1"` (the same for all data of `"name"` column). Probably it's just typing error during preparing of your question on the stackoverflow.

Comment: But i don't want to use the rowid, i want to use the id("7") coming in the Json respone  sothat the url will be 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7' if i use the row id then it will return 1(not 7)

Comment: @Subratnayak.: The value of `id` property of every item of data will be assigned as the value of **`id` attribute of the row** (<tr> element). jqGrid names `id` of the row as the rowid. So `options.rowId` of the item having `"id":7` will be `"7"`. You should just try this and you will the URL generated by formatter.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
colNames:['Id','Name','Category','Subcategory'],
colModel:[
          {name:'id',index:'id', width:150, hidden: true},
          {name:'person',index:'person', width:150},
          {name:'type',index:'type', width:150},
          {name:'name',index:'name', width:150,     
          formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                       var pageId = jQuery('[id="' + options.rowId + '"]').find('td:first').text();
                       return '<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + pageId + '">' +
                       cellvalue + '</a>';
          }
```

Try putting hidden true and get the text from this td.

Comment: But i don't want to use the rowid, i want to use the id("7") coming in the Json respone  sothat the url will be 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7' if i use the row id then it will return 1(not 7)

Comment: Okay then you have to do with column names and column models. wait for a while...